# Highchart dependencyWheel DataLabels positioning

Tags: highcharts, label

I'm using highcart to render few charts in a dashboard but I found a problem while using styledMode for dependency wheel

As you can see by this screenshot some of my datalabels move to the topleft of the chart. How can solve it?

I have other several chart that works in styledMode and taht's why I think to use it also in this chart.

If I remove the styledMode I miss the color similarity between nodes and link.

If someone can help understanding how to solve in one way or in the other it will be much appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug. I reported it on GitHub issue channel: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13406

Please follow this thread. If you need a temporary workaround - ask about it in the comment. Core developers will respond to you.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. finally  I move everything to non style mode.